# 'TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface' - python 3.4 conversion from 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert from python 2.7 to 3.4 and get the following error when trying to use `b64encode`:

```
from base64 import b64encode

username = 'manager'
password = 'test.manager'

headers = {"Authorization": " Basic " + b64encode(username + ":" + password), "Content-Type": "application/json"}
```

***Error***:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python34\Lib\base64.py", line 62, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s)[:-1]
**TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bytes` objects instead:

```
username = b'manager'
password = b'test.manager'

headers = {"Authorization": b" Basic " + b64encode(username + b":" + password), "Content-Type": "application/json"}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks cdonts